# Good books or lecture notes about logic of graphs.

Tags: logic, graph-theory, reference-request, model-theory, book-recommendation

Does anyone have a recommendation for a book to use for the self study of [logic of graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_of_graphs)?

I am interested in the following topics:

1. Data compression and graph isomorphism. Logical depth of a graph.
2. Get efficient algorithms out of FOL expressions
3. Courcelle's theorem
4. Machine learning / AI
5. Computer science (algorithmic) point of view